# Image of the square root function in the complex plane

Tags: complex-analysis

Using the principal branch of the square root function, that is the entire complex plane excluding the negative real axis, then the image of the square root function would have to be identical to the pre-image yes?  Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1):

Principal branch of square root is defined on $\mathbb C \setminus (-\infty, 0]$, and it's image is $\{z | -\frac{\pi}{2} < \arg(z) < \frac{\pi}{2}\}$.

Comment: what would be the image of $x=2$, since $-\frac{\pi}{2}<arg(z)<\frac{\pi}{2}$ this should be something in the right half plane. Right?